# The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. [007]

Tags: flutter

I just installed flutter 3.3.5 [stabel] mac arm64, on my Macbook Air M1, and every time I get The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Download and install 3.3.5 arm64
2. run `flutter doctor`

**Logs and `flutter doctor -v`**

```
The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Comment: Where did you install flutter?

Comment: At $HOME checked all the permissions and tried every possible solution!

Comment: What is the output if `which flutter`?